# Как сохранить картинку, созданную через Image.new?

Tags: python, изображения, pillow, pil

Представим, есть такая строка в коде:

```
   img = Image.new(mode="RGB", size=(360, 360))
```

Как мне переменную `img` сохранить в файл?

Comment: `img.save(...)` смотрите докуметацию `pillow` там расписано

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы таки будете смеяться, но с помощью метода `save`:

```
img.save('image.png')
```

А вообще как бы ну полезно читать [документацию](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/tutorial.html#reading-and-writing-images)